# EF Code First BaseContext-class

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've seen a tutorial where a dbcontext base class is created like so:

```
public class BaseContext<TContext> : DbContext where TContext : DbContext
{
    public BaseContext()
        : base("name=Context")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<TContext>(null);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
    }
}
```

And when it's inherited by a context-class:

```
public abstract class Context : BaseContext<Context>
{}
```

Now, I like the idea of a base-context class, but I don't see the advantage of making it a generic. Could it be implemented like this also?

```
public abstract class BaseContext : DbContext
{
    protected BaseContext()
        : base("name=Context")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<BaseContext>(null);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! [Example code is off-topic at Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use your second choice, as there is little chance of having operations working directly with context within your context. Generally speaking, [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/291254/advantage-of-generic-base-class) you can find out a question and answer about advantages of generic base classes.